# Metro Style Hybrid Apps - C# + WebViews vs. JavaScript + WinRT C++ - What's the best choice?

Tags: c#, c++, microsoft-metro, hybrid

I was wondering what would the best choice for building a Metro Style Hybrid App?

On one hand it would be a common solution to write a app in C#/XAML and use HTML5/JavaScript/CSS3 inside a WebView - that's the way I would do it on iOS or Android.

On the other hand it seems to be a great idea of writing a Metro Style App based on web technologies and only use native code (with WinRT Components) if really needed, for example encryption or image manipulation.

*What would be the smarter way? What are the advantages/disadvantages of both ways?
Is C++ the only native lanquage to use with WinRT Components communicating with JavaScript?*

It would be awesome if you could give me some advice - Thank you! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Few weeks ago we made a Proof-of-Concept to investigate the possibilities of cross-platform hybrid metro-style apps.
We used HTML5/JS/CSS as you mentioned, we deployed it using PhoneGap. The smooth, responsive UI required some engineering, the finalist candidates were iScroll and KnockOut.js libraries.

We optimized to Android/iPad tablets, Android 2.3+, and iPhone.
You can watch the result here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6MiKPX8OTo

I'm really interested in your experience, so please keep me posted about your results!

Comment: Please keep me posted about the results of your research or other alternatives